# How to handle emoji in custom framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding, emoji

I am facing certain problems with emojies like:

1. Looking for a consolidated library which can handle all the available emoji.
2. It should also support all the available platforms.
3. How to save quoted printed characters in the database?

Looking for someone who can answer these question or help me out.

Thanks,

Comment: @cosmo0 neither is progs.SE.

Comment: Darn. I would have sworn. So there is no good place to ask these questions after all :(

Comment: Yes there is a place ! http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ I forgot about this one. So may programming SE sites !

Comment: @cosmo0 this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: This might work for Software Recommendations, but they have their own set of standards. This question still requires work before it would be on topic there.

Comment: If you guys don't have answer, it's ok. Just got good information from Rick

Answer (score 2):

If you will store the emoji in a MySQL table, you will need `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  In PHP, use set_charset('utf8mb4') if you are using `mysqli_*`, or add specify that charset in the dsn if using PDO.  If using html, have a meta tag that specifies `utf-8`.